# Git get source difference commit

Tags: ios, git, commit, difference

I have a commit with english version of the app. The next commit would have many changes and all of them directed to translating the app to french language. Many files would be changed. So we can imagine two commits.

After that i gonna work further in this branch and add some features (with french language). But after a while i need to have a single commit to apply with cherry-pick to translate the app back to english.

How can i achieve this? (Please ask if i didn't explain clearly)
My idea is that i need to find a difference between eng and fr commits, reverse it and store at the separate branch. But i don't know if there a functional for that.
The additional info - the app is for ios, written with swift.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought (with lots of assumptions) - perhaps the better way would be to split the module into 3: one for common, language-independent files, one with English-specific files and one with French-specific files.

Then, make the English & French modules a sub-module of the common one ([git submodule docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)) and then the commits could be isolated by module.

Of course, perhaps the layout of the directories don't easily facilitate this...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked up submodules docs. My app is for ios and so it's easier to add an internatialization files than to split the project, because lot of strings are hardcoded in the code. So sorry, but your answer doesn't fit(